# How to replace 0 with missing values in Stata 17?

Tags: stata

I have a problem with changing zeros to missing values in Stata. When  I try to change it this comes up:

```
replace Political_spectrum= . if Political_spectrum== 0
(0 real changes made)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `replace Political_spectrum = 0 if Political_spectrum == .` should work.

Comment: It´s still not working, the same thing comes up.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the variable, e.g. using tabulate.

Comment: execrlc |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          0 |         85       52.15       52.15
     Center |         11        6.75       58.90
       Left |         39       23.93       82.82
      Right |         28       17.18      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |        163      100.00

Comment: With the -missing- option.

Comment: How should I write it? Sorry, i´m very new at Stata.

Comment: This thread is contradictory, as (1) it turns out that you really do want zeros to be treated as missing, so the wording is the wrong way round (2) but if so, the code should have worked! I have to guess that you're jumping back and forth between different variables in your dataset.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for the standard to aim at on SO.  (Note that the question refers to `Political_spectrum` but one comment lists results for `execrlc`.)

Answer (score 3):

`replace Political_spectrum = 0 if missing(Political_spectrum)`

Answer (score 0):

To check on missing values, you can go

```
tabulate Political_spectrum, missing
```

and if necessary

```
tabulate Political_spectrum, missing nolabel
```

as extended missing values `.a` to `.z` may be present and may be under a value label.

Comment: You're still giving  information  indirectly -- especially on exactly how you "changed" it from string to numeric  and by not showing in your question the results of `tabulate` either before or after the change.  But in essence you probably applied `encode`. You're thinking that 0 means missing but Stata really doesn't know that. As you're dealing with a variable that has values 1, 2, 3, 4 absolutely nothing is missing which explains your puzzlement. A separate problem is that `encode` uses alphanumeric sort order, but Left Center Right should surely be in that order, or the reverse.

Comment: Your variable needs to be jettisoned. You need to `replace` string `"0"` by an empty string `""` and then to define value labels `1 "Left" 2 "Center" 3 "Right"` and then call up `encode` with those value labels.